# Generate random number for each row where condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this example dataframe:

| id | names | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | name1 | jflsdf3r8fhldfskdjbf29 |
| 1111 | name2 | sljncidbviwbedsdvjfb |
| 2222 | name1 | jflsdf3r8fhldfskdjbf29 |
| 3333 | name2 | sadovnadnfadfadgdaf |
| 4444 | name2 | sadovnadnfadfadgdaf |

I want to add 4th column `random_number`, where I can generate random number for each row where the code is the same. Also if the code is the same the random_number should be the same for the rest of the rows where the `id` is the same. Expected output:

| id | names | code | random_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | name1 | jflsdf3r8fhldfskdjbf29 | 1 |
| 1111 | name2 | sljncidbviwbedsdvjfb | 1 |
| 2222 | name1 | jflsdf3r8fhldfskdjbf29 | 1 |
| 3333 | name2 | sadovnadnfadfadgdaf | 2 |
| 4444 | name2 | sadovnadnfadfadgdaf | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
code_to_namber = {}

def fill_number_to_code(code, dcit_code_to_num):
    if code not in dcit_code_to_num:
        dcit_code_to_num[code] = random.randint(a, b)
    return dcit_code_to_num[code]

df['random_number'] = df.code.apply(lambda x: fill_number_to_code(x,code_to_namber))
```

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html for additional random data like seed
replace a and b with the range of the random numbers you want